# Proof that $\langle \dot{O} \rangle = \text{Tr}(\dot{\rho}O)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, time-evolution

I'm reading a paper ([[PRB]](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.205432),[[arXiv]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02999); first paragraph of section IV) that uses the identity

$$\langle \dot{O} \rangle = \text{Tr}(\dot{\rho}O),$$

where $\rho$ is the density matrix, and $O$ is an arbitrary operator. I am hoping for a proof for this identity.

Comment: Should the left hand side be read as $\left\langle\frac{d O}{dt}\right\rangle$ or as $\frac{d\langle O\rangle}{dt}$?

Comment: @BySymmetry My guess is that it is the latter, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

$\langle O\rangle$ is by definition equal to $\mathrm{tr}[\rho O]$.  Since $O$ is time-independent, the result immediately follows - at least if you interpret the LHS as the derivative of the expectation value.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that at thermal equilibrium all expectation values are fixed in time, therefore time-derivative must come from changes in the density matrix (reflecting nonequilibrium).

To see this (assuming that $O$ is independent of time by itself):
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \langle O \rangle = \frac{d}{dt}{\rm Tr} \left\{ \rho O \right\} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_n \langle n | \rho O | n\rangle = i \sum_{n} \langle n | \mathcal{H}\rho O - O \rho \mathcal{H} |n\rangle + \sum_{n} \langle n|\dot{\rho}O|n\rangle$$
The first term drops because the trace is cyclic (which exactly means that at thermal equilibrium there is no time dependence). So we are left with the second term alone.